# Configure JDK for running Maven inside Dockerfile based on tomcat:9

Tags: maven, docker, java

I am trying to build a Docker image based on the standard Docker image [`tomcat:9`](https://hub.docker.com/_/tomcat/) that can also compile Java using Maven:

When I first `docker run` `tomcat:9` I get these results:

```
java -version                       # openjdk version "1.8.0_102"
javac -version                      # javac: command not found
echo $JAVA_HOME                     # /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
dpkg --get-selections | grep \\-jre # openjdk-8-jre-headless:amd64
dpkg --get-selections | grep \\-jdk # (none)
update-alternatives --config java   
# There is only one alternative in link group java (providing /usr/bin/java)
update-alternatives --config javac  # error: no alternatives for javac
```

When I then `docker build` a derived Docker image with this `Dockerfile`

```
FROM tomcat:9
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y openjdk-7-jdk maven
```

and `docker run` it I get these results:

```
java -version                       # java version "1.7.0_111"
javac -version                      # javac 1.7.0_111
echo $JAVA_HOME                     # /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
dpkg --get-selections | grep \\-jre # default-jre, default-jre-headless, openjdk-7-jre:amd64, openjdk-7-jre-headless:amd64, openjdk-8-jre-headless:amd64
dpkg --get-selections | grep \\-jdk # penjdk-7-jdk:amd64
update-alternatives --config java   # (3 alternatives 
# /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java, 
# /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java, 
# /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java,
# with the 1st one selected)
update-alternatives --config javac  
# There is only one alternative in link group java (providing /usr/bin/javac)
```

However, if I then `RUN mvn package` in the same Dockerfile (and in I directory where my `pom.xml` exists),
I get this error message:

```
No compiler is provided in this environment. 
Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?
```

How can I make Maven aware of the installed JDK (instead of JRE) in this environment?

Is `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64` (i.e. changing `JAVA_HOME` manually) the correct way to go or is there a better way, e.g. in terms of system integrity?

Comment: For what reason do you need Java 7 that the provided Java 8 cannot do?

Comment: @cricket_007 I need a JDK (w/ `javac`) instead of JRE (w/o `javac`). The version is only of secondary importance. JDK 8 would be fine as well.

Comment: I see. I think the standard approach is to compile your app independently from the container, then link a volume into the WebRoot of the server

Comment: @cricket_007 Your first question was a good one. If I `RUN apt-get install -y openjdk-8-jdk maven` (i.e. install JDK 8 instead of JDK 7) in the `Dockerfile` the problem *somehow* goes away.

Comment: Probably because the Java 8 installer correctly overrides the `JAVA_HOME` variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default tomcat:9 Docker image comes with JRE 8. So, you just need to  install **JDK 8** to use the javac.

```
apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk maven
```